# Normal Plot (visual test for normality)

Tags: plotting

I wish to construct a Normal Plot to visually test for normality of data.  My data is:

> {188,199,171,200,219,172,235,194,234,206}

And needs to be plotted to look something like this:

[image]

Whereby the data points are sorted from low to high and then plotted against the mid-point of their probability bins.  So, in this case there are 10 data points so 10 bins with mid points of 5%, 15%, 25% etc. For this data, you would then see the lowest value (171) plotted at (171,5%), the next value (172) plotted at (172,15%) and so on.

Any ideas where I can find the answers?

Comment: So the values of the list (sorted) are placed on the horizontal axis. Can you give us the formula for calculating the y-axis values? Once this is specified, the plot is straightforward.

Comment: You might be looking for `ProbabilityScalePlot`.

Comment: @bill s There are many formulas possible; a common one is `InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], y = Range[1/2, n + 1/2]/(n + 1)]] /` where `n` is the length of the sorted data list. The y-axis ticks are labeled with `100 y`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this [`ProbabilityScalePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProbabilityScalePlot.html) does what you are looking for.

```
data = {188, 199, 171, 200, 219, 172, 235, 194, 234, 206};    

ProbabilityScalePlot[data, GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> "Classic"]
```

[image]

Comment: This is available beginning in Version 9.

Comment: @whuber Actually, it was version 8.  But worth pointing out nonetheless.

Comment: Not quite /// the vertical axis scaling is very different to what the OP seeks.

Comment: `ProbabilityScalePlot[data,"Normal", GridLines-> {Range[170,230,15],Range[5,95,5]}, PlotRange-> {Automatic,{0.1,99.9}}, PlotMarkers-> Style["\[FilledSquare]",Darker[Orange]]]` 
provides the cosmetic change needed to more closely match the original picture.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks team.  I didn't find the `ProbabilityScalePlot` in my search but it is exactly what I was after.